# Insert data to fragments from db. Is there any difference from common insertion method?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

This is my code for insertion, When i put this code to activity it is working well, but in fragment it is not working.

```
View.OnClickListener addOnClickListener=new OnClickListener()
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         String HouseName = "home";//txtName.getText().toString();
        Integer HouseNumber =12; //Integer.parseInt(txtNumber.getText().toString());
         String TableName="home_details";

         dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
         sqlitedatabase=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
         dbhelper.insertHome(HouseName, HouseNumber, sqlitedatabase);
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext() ,"Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         dbhelper.close();

     }
 };
```

Comment: Any error logs?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: which line has nullpinter exception ?

Comment: fragment stops forcefully when i click on insert button... don't know which line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the full logcat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code:

```
dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
```

I think the NullPointException is because of context is null.

Comment: That is assuming the null-pointer occurs in the code shown in the question

Comment: @Aadhi Glad to hear that.